# How to detect copy event and add an extra text to it?

Tags: android

How to detect copy event and add an extra text to it?

I've tried doing it like this:

```
  //onCreate:    
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mPrimaryChangeListener);
 //End onCreate:    


ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mPrimaryChangeListener = 
   new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
     public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
       ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

       String clipText = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

       ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label",clipText +" by Jhon");
       clipBoard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
};
```

But it doesn't make a difference , it only copy the selected text without `" by John"` notation.